# getaddrinfo() with AI_FQDN on Win10 returns only the workstation name in ai_canonname for a Win8 workstation?

Tags: winapi, winsock, winsock2, wnet

In general using `getaddrinfo()` in Win10 application with the hint for `AI_FQDN` works.  But I have a Windows 8 workstation on the network that returns only the workstation name, not the FQDN like the other workstations on the network.  It's joined to the domain just like the others.

Any idea why this workstation doesn't return the actual FQDN?  I presume I'd run in to this on other networks too?

TIA!!

Comment: Use Wireshark to see what traffic is going over the wire.